# How to grab 2 products for each department?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to grab 2 products for each department. A `department` has many `aisles`, an `aisle` has many `products`.

Why isn't the `LIMIT` in the `LATERAL` working? At the moment, it is returning more that 2 products.

I've got:

```
SELECT d.id, p.* FROM departments d
JOIN aisles a ON d.id = a.department_id, LATERAL (
  SELECT * FROM products p1 WHERE p1.aisle_id = a.id ORDER BY p1.id ASC LIMIT 2
) p
WHERE a.department_id IN (3,5);
```

Which returns:

```
 id | id  |  aisle_id |            name             |  image_filename |         created_at         |         updated_at
----+-----+-----------+-----------------------------+-----------------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  3 | 149 |        11 | Sleek Wool Watch            |  foo.png        | 2015-10-30 10:03:21.107873 | 2015-10-30 10:03:21.107873
  3 |   3 |        12 | Heavy Duty Granite Lamp     |  foo.png        | 2015-10-30 10:03:20.637513 | 2015-10-30 10:03:20.637513
  3 |  88 |        12 | Rustic Marble Shirt         |  foo.png        | 2015-10-30 10:03:20.883394 | 2015-10-30 10:03:20.883394
  3 |  56 |        13 | Enormous Linen Bottle       |  foo.png        | 2015-10-30 10:03:20.786546 | 2015-10-30 10:03:20.786546
  5 |  22 |        24 | Gorgeous Linen Clock        |  foo.png        | 2015-10-30 10:03:20.687868 | 2015-10-30 10:03:20.687868
  5 | 104 |        24 | Synergistic Leather Bag     |  foo.png        | 2015-10-30 10:03:20.933504 | 2015-10-30 10:03:20.933504
  5 |  80 |        25 | Enormous Leather Bag        |  foo.png        | 2015-10-30 10:03:20.860636 | 2015-10-30 10:03:20.860636
  5 | 117 |        25 | Aerodynamic Bronze Gloves   |  foo.png        | 2015-10-30 10:03:21.015299 | 2015-10-30 10:03:21.015299
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you need to mention LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL and ON True,which will fix your issue .

```
SELECT d.id, p.* FROM departments d
JOIN aisles a ON d.id = a.department_id LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT * FROM products p1 WHERE p1.aisle_id = a.id ORDER BY p1.id ASC LIMIT 2
) p
ON True
WHERE a.department_id IN (3,5);
```

More information here
[What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql)